# How to pull text from the same page and use it in a calculation

Tags: html

I'm working on a page that I want to display reviews on from multiple places. We'll have to update these stats by hand once in a while but I want to enter the amount of reviews and the average number those reviews would give (example: 4.8 based on 5 reviews).

How can I enter the amount of reviews and the number of reviews so that I can make a calculation at the top of the page showing the average of all those platforms combined without having to do that calculation by hand?

Is this possible within HTML?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML has the `<output>` element that could help you with that. Although given that you're updating all these things manually, I'd argue you should just make a dynamic website and use JavaScript to add these values

[W3Schools — **output**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp) 
[MDN docs — **output**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output)

Here's an example of how to use it:

```js
let numerator = document.getElementById('numerator').innerHTML;
let denominator = document.getElementById('denominator').innerHTML;
let result = document.getElementById('result');

result.innerHTML = parseInt(numerator) / parseInt(denominator);
```

```html
<span id='numerator'>17</span> /
<span id='denominator'>20</span> =

<output id='result'></output>
```

However it's impossible to do this without JavaScript, since HTML is designed to be a markup language and a markup language *only*. You won't be able to run code like calculations directly in your HTML anytime soon.
That's why the MDN docs themselves resort to inline JavaScript to load in the result, which by the way should be avoided.

My personal tip is to make a dynamic website. You need a lot of JavaScript to handle what you're trying to do, which is display dynamic information to the user, and that cannot be done without a backend.

Comment: Does this simply base values given with a certain ID? Or does it have to be an input element?

Comment: @Pixel I edited my answer to better explain the solution :)